# No encuentro la sección de "Include paths" de Eclipse (Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)) en Linux Mint

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, linux-mint

He estado tratando de utilizar la librería de OpenCV en Eclipse (Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)) en Linux Mint (Linux Mint 20.3 Una \n \l).

Instalé OpenCV con el siguiente tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLohXMh6XZY

He seguido el siguiente tutorial para utilizar OpenCV:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d16/tutorial_linux_eclipse.html

El nombre del proyecto es "Mostrar imagen"

Todo bien hasta el paso 8. en la parte donde dice:
Go to Project–>Properties
In C/C++ Build

¡no existe la sección "C/C++ Build"!

(imagino que algo cambió en la versión de eclipse que estoy utilizando).

Lo más aproximado que encontré es al dar clic en "C/C++ General" aparece una opción "Configure Workspace Settings" que abre más opciones y existe la sección C/C++ -> Build -> Setings pero no tiene el apartado "Tool Settings" ni mucho menos "Includes" o "Include paths" (ver captura).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que hacer para poder añadir la referencia a OpenCV

Nota:
al ejecutar el comando:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

Para obtener la dirección de donde está instalado OpenCV me regresa:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2
```

Doy gracias a todos los que me ayuden a solucionar esto.

---------------------------actualización---------------------------

descubrí que no aparecía la sección "C/C++ Build" porque cree un proyecto de tipo equivocado, el Toolchains tenia que específicamente ser "Linux GCC".

entonces la primera parte de la sección 8. del tutorial esté resuelta pero al final de la misma sección el tutorial indica que hay que dar en:

Project->Build all

Que me da como resultado el siguiente error (nota: cree de nuevo el proyecto y se llama ahora p_i y el source file es p_i.cpp):

```
16:01:34 **** Build of configuration Debug for project p_i ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/p_i.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/p_i.d" -MT"src/p_i.o" -o "src/p_i.o" "../src/p_i.cpp"
../src/p_i.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No existe el archivo o el directorio
    1 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/p_i.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

16:01:34 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 186ms)
```

Estoy investigando al respecto, puede que tenga que ver con que cuando ejecuto el comando:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

Me regresa lo siguiente:

-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui

Es decir que no me indica su ubicación.

seguiré buscando una solución...

Comment: Supongo que ya habrás buscado opencv+eclipse+linux en el buscador. Por si acaso, haciéndolo veo este enlace https://jeanvitor.com/installing-linux-opencv-eclipse/ . A ver si hay suerte y alguien te da mejor ayuda.

Comment: por desgracia, como puedes ver el menú de Eclipse del tutorial que compartiste y el mío son distintos

Answer (score 0):

por fin funcionó cuando cambié la ruta "/usr/include/opencv" por "/usr/local/include/opencv4", la verdad no se porque.

gracias a todos los que leyeron y trataron de ayudar con esto.